# AngularJS controller not displaying data from array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I'm currently working on some code in Angular which loads a list of blogposts to a website. I have a module and controller, and have an ng-repeat loop set up to iterate through a json which acts as an index for a bunch of html files. However, the tags which should be outputting data from my index object are all empty on the final page.

app.js:

```
var PersonalApp = angular.module('PersonalApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'MasterCtrl'
]);

PersonalApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/blog', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/blog.html',
        MasterCtrl: 'MasterCtrl'

      }).
      when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
        MasterCtrl: 'MasterCtrl'

      }).
      when('/projects', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
        MasterCtrl: 'MasterCtrl'

      }).
      when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
        MasterCtrl: 'MasterCtrl'

      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/blog'
      });
  }]);
```

MasterCtrl.js:

```
var MasterCtrl = angular.module('MasterCtrl', []);

MasterCtrl.controller('MasterCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../BlogPosts/posts.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (bposts) {
                $scope.bposts = (bposts);
                bposts = JSON.stringify(bposts)
                console.log(bposts);
            }
        });
    }]);
```

blog.html:

```
<article ng-repeat="posts in bposts" class="post-173 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-uncategorized masonry-brick" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                <div class="item-sizer">

                    <header class="entry-header blog-entry-header">

                        <div class="entry-data">
                            <span class="posted-on">
                                <a ng-href="/../BlogPosts/{{posts.ID}}" rel="bookmark">
                                    <time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="2015-08-20T02:48:02+00:00">{{posts.ID}}</time>
                                </a>
                            </span>

                        </div>
                        <h1 class="entry-title"><a ng-href="/../BlogPosts/{{posts.ID}}" rel="bookmark">{{posts.Title}}</a></h1> </header><!-- .entry-header -->
                        {[posts.ID}}

                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <p>{{posts.Summary}}<a class="read-more" ng-href="/../BlogPosts/{{posts.ID}}">Continue reading</a></p>
                    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                </div>
            </article>
```

---

Here is the console output of my originally jQuery:

```
{"posts":[{
    "ID":"441770384",
    "Title":"TestPost",
    "Summary":"Doot Doot",
    "Thumb":"null"
},{
    "ID":"1441835958",
    "Title":null,
    "Summary":"null",
    "Thumb":"‌​null"
},{
    "ID":"1441836000",
    "Title":null,
    "Summary":"null",
    "Thumb":"null"
},{
    "ID":"14‌​41836039",
    "Title":"dfasdf",
    "Summary":"null",
    "Thumb":"null"
}]}
```

Comment: use `$http` instead of `$.ajax` so you don't have to use `$apply()` for each request. Angular doesn't know about `$.ajax` so you have to tell it to run digests when you change scope.

Comment: Congrats on separating your app into modules, it's a rare site on StackOverflow. You'll find it much easier to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using jQuery's `.ajax` method instead of `$http`. Using jQuery won't trigger a digest cycle and as such, your scope changes won't be reflected in your templates. Use `$http` instead...

Simply change your *"MasterCtrl"* controller to

```
.controller('MasterCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('../BlogPosts/posts.json').then(function(response) {
            $scope.bposts = response.data.posts;
        });
    }]);
```

and try to avoid using jQuery in Angular apps.

See [`$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) for more information about the digest cycle and what you should do if you insist on using third party libraries like jQuery.

Comment: I had this originally, but it wasn't working either. Just tried your code and it didn't work.

Comment: @AdrianSmith *"didn't work"* isn't a very good problem description. What does the data in `posts.json` look like?

Comment: Using your version of the code had no change on what the actual page looks like. 

Here is the console output of my originally jQuery: {"posts":[{"ID":"441770384","Title":"TestPost","Summary":"Doot Doot","Thumb":"null"},{"ID":"1441835958","Title":null,"Summary":"null","Thumb":"null"},{"ID":"1441836000","Title":null,"Summary":"null","Thumb":"null"},{"ID":"1441836039","Title":"dfasdf","Summary":"null","Thumb":"null"}]}

Comment: Console output is also identical after using your code.

Comment: @AdrianSmith then you simply need to reference the `posts` property of the response data instead. See updated answer

Comment: @Romulo `$scope.$apply()` will throw an error in my answer. It is totally unnecessary here

Comment: @Phil, Okay, so that works much better. I am getting the desired data to show up on blog.html... Kinda. Now only one posts shows, the code isn't iterating through the list. I'm thinking it's because I', now calling the posts object in MasterCtrl, my syntax for iteration no longer makes sense. Not sure though, still a bit lost.

Comment: @AdrianSmith you sure you're not just absolutely positioning them one on top of the other? I see they all have `style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"`

Comment: thanks, that was exactly the problem! Now I just have to fix formatting stuff. Thanks so much, I have no idea what I would do without you fantastic people! The reason a lot of the html code is so wonky is that I'm basically trying to take a WP theme I saw and liked, and redesign it myself as a stand-alone website in Angular for the practice.

Comment: @AdrianSmith You're welcome. Good luck with the design

Answer (score 0):

Since you are retrieving your data using JQuery ($.ajax), you have to invoke the $scope.$apply() so AngularJS can create the binding and update your view.

You can check [When to use $scope.$apply()](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29) for more info.

Comment: Where would I use that?

Comment: You should use that after you assign the retrieved data to your scope variable. In your case that would be after **$scope.bposts = (bposts);**

Comment: I switched to the non-jQuery version of the code as suggested by @Phil, but the same issue is still occurring.

Comment: OP shouldn't be using `$.ajax` at all, especially since they're even injecting the `$http` service.